# MySQL Update field of set IF NULL or other value

Tags: mysql

I am currently using two update queries and am wondering if there is a way to cut it down to one.

```
field1 OFTYPE INT
field2 OFTYPE DATETIME
field3 OFTYPE DATETIME

UPDATE `Table1` SET `field1` = `field1` + 1, `field2` = NOW() WHERE `id` = $id;
UPDATE `Table1` SET `field3` = NOW() WHERE `id` = $id AND (`field3` < '2011-00-00 00:00:00' OR `field3` IS NULL);
```

I'm trying to get a query that would do the UPDATE more like so:

```
UPDATE `Table1` 
SET `field1` = `field1` + 1,
    `field2` = NOW(),
    `field3` = ISNULL(NOW(), `first_seen`);
```

Comment: An update insert or delete statement can only update one table/view. Nice try though!

Comment: @HarHaHu the OP updates only one table, so this is perfectly fine.

Comment: @HarHaHu it is just one table  as I read it ;)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think that's it's possible for you to do this using an IF statement.  The IF statement takes 3 parameters when you're using it: the expression, value if true, value if false

So in your case, you could probably write your queries in one go like the following:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET 
    field1 = field1 + 1, 
    field2 = NOW(),
    field3 = IF(field3 < '2011-00-00 00:00:00' OR field3 IS NULL, NOW(), field3)
WHERE id = $id;
```

This way, if expression is true, then `field3` will be `NOW()` and otherwise, it'll remain as it was.

Comment: The date causes a mysql error, change to '2011-01-01 00:00:00'

Answer (score 16):

In your case you could use `CASE`*:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET field1 = field1 + 1,
  field2 = NOW(),
  field3 =
        CASE
        WHEN field3 < '2011-00-00 00:00:00' THEN /* Evaluates to false if NULL */
          NOW()
        WHEN field3 IS NULL THEN
          NOW()
        ELSE /* Don't change */
          field3
        END
WHERE id = 1
```

*Pun optional

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like that:

```
UPDATE `Table1` 
SET `field1` = `field1` + 1,
    `field2` = NOW(),
    `field3` = COALESCE(field3, NOW())
WHERE id = 1;
```

This will update all field1 and field2 and if field3 is null will update it too, if its not null it will remain what it was. But this works only for NULL!!!

Comment: much less code than a whole tenary operator-like if statement

Answer (score 0):

If `field3` have to be updated with a different condition from `field1` and `field2`, I suppose that you can't do all in one query.
What you can do is a [TRANSACTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) if the queries have to be executed together or nothing.